# Is there anyway to "add" tables to existing database when using Code First?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I want to add a module build on Code First to a running website, which already has an database. If I set my module to run on separated database, it works fine.

But my friend want to just "add" tables created by my modules to existing database, without adding a new database.

Is there anyway to archive that?

Comment: (I've never understood "Code First" .. in any case, +1 and good luck.)

Comment: You need to look at [code-first migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) to solve that "problem"

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple and very easy:

- Run the module to create a new, clean database
- Use SQL Server to generate sql scripts that create tables of that database. I personally think the metadata table is not needed
- Run those scripts against target database
- Modify the connection string to point to target database

Now it runs flawless! I'm so happy

Thank you.